# Display multicolumn graph

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

I am currently working on a c# wpf project where I want to display a chart to the user. I'm using WPF C# .net 4 and using the built in chart library but I can't find anything about the type of chart I want it to use. A screen shot below is the type of chart that I am looking for.
[image]

I have a single column chart working I.e. one bar for each month instead of being able to have 2 more columns per a month.

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right chart, you just need to add another series :

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart
  Title="Debits and credits"
  DataContext="{StaticResource MyDataCollection}">
  <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries
    Title="Credits"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}"
    IndependentValuePath="Month"
    DependentValuePath="Credit" />
  <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries
    Title="Debits"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}"
    IndependentValuePath="Month"
    DependentValuePath="Debit" />
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, works great, spent ages looking on google and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to determine exactly what you want, based on your description, but if I had to guess, I would say you want a stacked bar chart. This way you could have a single bar with debits stacked on top of credits or credits stacked on top of credits.

BTW, I don't know if this will help you, but I recently researched a number of WPF chart controls for a very important manufacturing application I'm involved in. I found Visifire to be the best WPF control I could find when comparing cost to features. And I have no affiliation with them.

Comment: Thanks I was looking for a free version, its only going to be a small project so not worth spending that kind of money which is why I was hoping to use the built in .net 4 library. Basically I've got it working to show one column for each month, i.e. only debits, but I can't get it to work to show multiple columns for each month, i.e.  debits and credits per a month

Comment: Ok. I now see what you want to do. I don't know what functionality the charting control that you use supports. But I'm pretty sure you're going to have to create two data series. One will be for debits and the other will be for credits. The X axis for each will be the month.